# Distributed NoSQL database for Raspberry Pi with sharding and replication?

Tags: nosql, raspberry-pi

I am looking for a database with the following features:

- Runs on Raspberry Pi
- NoSQL (Key-Value-Store)
- Transaction support
- Distributed
- Supports sharding
- Supports automatically managed data redundancy across several nodes so that single nodes may join and leave, similar as in a P2P network

Basically, Redis would be exactly what I want - but Redis runs completely in-memory which is a massive drawback on the Raspberry Pi.

Any other ideas?

PS: A P2P network or a distributed file system with the given characteristics is fine for me as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) will work on the Raspberry Pi quite nicely.  It should fill the bill of what you want to do.  I've been experimenting with it on my blog, go [here](http://ac31004.blogspot.co.uk) to see my results and setup information on my blog

However I noted you stated "transaction support" - are you sure of that?

Few NOSQL databases offer transaction support, although [FoundationDB](https://foundationdb.com/key-value-store/white-papers/transaction-processing) is one. It has all the features you requested with the exception of running on a Raspberry Pi, as it requires 64-bit.

Comment: Foundation only offers 64-bit linux build, tough luck for rasp pi.

Comment: I haven't played with it in depth, but apparently RavenDB does offer transaction support - http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/transaction-support

Comment: I didn't add the comment on Foundationdb.  However it has now been aquired by Apple and is no longer available .

Comment: And what if I dont want it to be distributed. I want to persist the sensor based time series data. But the problem is the DBMS has to be on a single raspberry pi where obviously my application would also be running. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have my Raspberry Pi yet, but I am really hoping that [Redis](http://redis.io/) runs on a Raspberry Pi.  From looking around the Redis website, there's no reason to believe it shouldn't.

Comment: I can confirm that Redis is a simple `apt-get install redis-server` away, at least if you're using the official Raspbian distribution. I can get 10k+ GETs per second on a B+, haven't benchmarked on a RPi 2 yet.

Comment: indeed it does and here I posted the steps to install and configure the latest stable straight from the source code. http://iamsensoria.com/post/134341909620/raspberry-pi-and-sensor-tag-part-iv

Answer (score 2):

There's [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), which offers the lot, but as all DBMS's are Memory, Storage and IO intensive, I don't now how practical a cluster or Pi's would be.  Note the transaction requirement is vague, could be met by Mongo's autonomous document updates, assuming 1 document = 1 transaction.

You can find several Mongo + RaspberryPi guides around e.g.

- [Scribble: Building MongoDB on Raspberry Pi](http://elsmorian.com/post/24395639198/building-mongodb-on-raspberry-pi)
- [How to install MongoDB on a Raspberry Pi…Really! | mongopi](http://mongopi.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/installation/)

Comment: For those afraid of compiling MongoDB for the Pi, you can try http://www.widriksson.com/install-mongodb-raspberrypi/ and install MongoDB directly from pre-compiled binaries

Answer (score 2):

Riak should work on clusters of Raspberry Pis. Here is a [tutorial](http://basho.com/building-a-riak-cluster-on-raspberry-pi/).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite should be considered too, if you ever liked SQL. Libraries are available for most of the languages and it's really easy to model your data for it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OrientDb](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/) is not a key-value type, but instead is a Document-Graph database, from the last release the 1.7 it support sharding and of course the distributed mode based on Hazelcast in multimaster node, it suport transaction, i think you can configure the [plocal](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Paginated-Local-Storage) storage to optimize the memory conumption but give a try at the default configuration i think that will work (I didn't try the lastes release on the RaspberryPi but with the oldest one i've had no problem)